# C# Unity Container Constructor Injection transient lifetime manager same instance served

Tags: c#, instance, unity-container, resolve, transient

**Problem:** I have some XSD generated models that are complex and I wanted to let Unity construct them. There are many nestings and arrays of classes within classes and I'd rather not new them up.

That given if I do that and use constructor injection, it seems I'm not getting a new model every time I use the generation class. My populated list contains records where all records reference the same instance.

This example simplifies the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using Unity;

namespace sandbox
{
    public class Test
    {
        private GetTestRec _getTestRec;

        public Test(GetTestRec getTestRec)
        {
            _getTestRec = getTestRec;
        }

        public void RunMe()
        {
            var mylist = new List<TestModel>();
            var InList = new List<StructIn>();

            InList.Add(new StructIn() { Name = "asd", Amount = 5.55F });
            InList.Add(new StructIn() { Name = "lkj", Amount = 1.00F });

            foreach (var item in InList)
            {
                mylist.Add(_getTestRec.Get(item));
            }

            foreach (var item in mylist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} {item.Amount}" );
            }
        }
    }

    public class GetTestRec
    {
        private TestModel _testModel;

        public GetTestRec(TestModel testModel)
        {
            //_testModel = testModel;
        }

        public TestModel Get(StructIn structIn)
        {
            _testModel = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<TestModel>();

            _testModel.Name = structIn.Name;
            _testModel.Amount = structIn.Amount;

            return _testModel;
        }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        public TestModel()
        { }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public struct StructIn
    {
        public string Name;
        public float Amount;
    }
}
```

In the above code the TestModel is being resolved explicitly. If I resolve the GetTestRec and execute RunMe()...

```
var testThis = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<Test>();
testThis.RunMe();
```

You can see that it correctly generates two instances of the TestModel and adds them to the list

**asd 5.55

lkj 1**

But if I comment out the explicit resolve and instead inject the TestModel through the constructor...

```
    public class GetTestRec
    {
        private TestModel _testModel;

        public GetTestRec(TestModel testModel)
        {
            _testModel = testModel;
        }

        public TestModel Get(StructIn structIn)
        {
            //_testModel = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<TestModel>();

            _testModel.Name = structIn.Name;
            _testModel.Amount = structIn.Amount;

            return _testModel;
        }
    }
```

You can see that it's only using one instance of the TestClass and all records in the list point to the same instance

**lkj 1

lkj 1**

How do I use the constructor injection and get a new instance every time? The default transient lifetime says it gets a new instance with every resolve and if I call resolve then I do get a new instance. But, using the constructor I don't believe resolve is called as it's already been previously resolved.

What is the best direction here? Is a Factory pattern with Unity where I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to return new model on every call to `TestModel Get` (essentially replacing `new TestModel` with some sort of DI friendly code.

Take dependency on factory method (as in `Func<TestModel>`) to create them as needed. With Unity you don't need to add any special registrations to get it working - it always registers both `T` and `Func<T>` (which is simply `container => container.Resolve<T>()`). With other containers you may need to either manually register it or even create factory interface.

```
public class GetTestRec
{
    private Func<TestModel> _testModelFactory;

    public GetTestRec(Func<TestModel> testModelFactory)
    {
        _testModelFactory = testModelFactory;
    }

    public TestModel Get(StructIn structIn)
    {
        TestModel newModel = _testModelFactory();

        newModel.Name = structIn.Name;
        newModel.Amount = structIn.Amount;

        return newModel;
    }
}
```